# Share internal Android App release with anyone?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

It's my first time publishing an Android App to the Play Store.
I'm faced with the following situation:

My app is currently in a pre-release state with some minor bugs. I would like to provide a download link in a cold email-campaign to a portion of my clients (around 100 testers) to collaborate on the product. 
Obviously I don't know all of their Google Account emails and it would be impractical to reach to every single one of them.

Is there a way to invite the testers to my internal testing track with just a download link? I don't mind if the testers share the link in their company ...
And is there ideally a way for me to see, which Google Accounts used that download link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use internal testing thru Google play but you have to specify emails allowed to download. Then you can give them the link from the internal test on the dev console.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know their Googel account email ... That's the problem

Comment: You could do an open beta test. That will allow you to only use a download link

Comment: Personally I would stick with the internal test and you'll just have to work to get the emails. I like to know exactly who is running my alpha/beta code. If you just share a link anyone can get it. Maybe for some apps it's not an important issue, but for what I do it is important to control the distribution for IP protection until the app is ready for release.